# Mongoose schema field names and types with subdocs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an object of field names and their types from my schema:

```
var ret = {};
ThisCollection.schema.eachPath(function(path) {
  ret[path] = ThisCollection.schema.path(path).instance;
});
```

Which is great unless there's a nested array in the schema. I can't seem to figure out how to access the subdocument and its fields' types. I've tried:

```
ThisCollection.schema.path("dot.notation").instance
```

within a recursive function building out the dot notation name of a deeper path. This does not appear to work.

Example schema:

```
 var Person = new Schema({
    person_code: String, 
    person_name: String, 
    location_details:[{
        location_name: String,
        location_code: String
    }]
});
```

To be clear, I'm looking for my return object to match my schema in structure as well, so that nested schemas are nested objects in my return object, something like:

```
{
    person_code: String,
    person_name: String,
    location_details:{
        location_name: String,
        location_code: String
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK Updated question for clarity

Comment: You've lost the fact that `location_details` is an array, is that what you want? What are you ultimately trying to do with this? It doesn't make much sense to me. Why not just save off your original schema definition object if that's what you need?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes I'm intentionally losing the array. I need for another functionality later to be able to "read" my declared schema (field names and their declared types), and my schemas are sometimes user-defined. I'm fairly new to Mongo/Mongoose/Node so there's a lot of little things I'm probably missing. You might be on to something with the original schema definition object, that's sort of what I was trying to access with `schema.paths`

Comment: @JohnnyHK You were on the right path, what I'm looking for is `ThisCollection.schema.tree`, do you want to post an answer then for the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to simply save off the schema definition object you're using to create your schema:

```
var personSchemaDef = {
    person_code: String,
    person_name: String,
    location_details: [{
        location_name: String,
        location_code: String
    }]
};
var personSchema = new Schema(personSchemaDef);
var Person = mongoose.model('person', personSchema, 'people');
```

But you can also get the hierarchical details of the schema from the `tree` property of the schema:

```
console.log(Person.schema.tree)
```

Output:

```
{ person_code: [Function: String],
  person_name: [Function: String],
  location_details:
   [ { location_code: [Function: String],
       location_name: [Function: String] } ],
  _id:
   { type: { [Function: ObjectId] schemaName: 'ObjectId' },
     auto: true },
  id:
   VirtualType {
     path: 'id',
     getters: [ [Function: idGetter] ],
     setters: [],
     options: {} },
  __v: [Function: Number] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to create an object from the paths, in particular the paths with the dot notation string. You can use the following method that sets an object given the property and value;

```
var ret = {};
var setObject = function(name, schema, context) {
    var parts = name.split("."), 
        p = parts.pop(),
        value = schema.path(p).instance;
    for(var i=0, j; context && (j=parts[i]); i++){
        context = (j in context ? context[j] : context[j]={});
    }        
    return context && p ? (context[p]=value) : undefined; // Object
}

ThisCollection.schema.eachPath(function(path) {         
    setObject(path, ThisCollection.schema, ret);        
});
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. `ThisCollection.schema.path(path).instance` does not appear to be working with a dot notation path.

Comment: That looks like it would work. I'll test it out and get back to you.

Comment: It still doesn't address the cursing through each level if there's one of them is an array or object.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the type of property of a subdoc by

```
[Collection].schema.paths.[sub-doc].schema.paths.[sub-doc-property].instance   // it will give dataytpe
```

you can nest it as how many nested sub-doc you have

for your collection you can use

```
ThisCollection.schema.paths.location_details.schema.paths.location_name.instance   // String
```

_

```
/**
* @param {Object} coll       - Collection
* @param {string} props      - properties, eg. "abc", "abc.xyz", upto n number of nested dot notation
*/
function getType(coll, props) {
    return props.split('.').reduce(function (p, n, index, array) {
        if (index < array.length - 1) {
            return p.schema.paths[n];
        }
        return p.schema.paths[n].instance;
    }, coll);
}

var type = getType(ThisCollection, "location_details.location_name");
console.log(type); // String
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the field names in a schema then this is a simple way to do it:

```
const schema = [dbname].schema; 
const fieldNames = Object.keys(schema.obj);
```

This will give you an array of field names.
The `schema.obj` also specifies the field type.